# Is there a way to insert a C# string into a SQL varbinary column?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in C# to insert rows of strings (via `Parameters.AddWithValue`) into SQL Server. One of the columns I need to insert into is a `Varbinary`. Is there any way to do the conversion in either C# or SQL Server?

Comment: You mean like `Encoding.UTF8Encoding.ToByteArray(string)`?

Comment: Can you post your code as well as an example of what and where in the code you want this conversion to take place

Comment: Couldn't you cast the string to a varbinary in your SQL?  Or do you want it stored in the DB as the original string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522605/why-is-convert-string-to-varbinary-in-sql-server-only-converting-first-character), you can use the `CONVERT` function to insert a string into a `VARBINARY` column. Make sure you use the proper encoding, as discussed in that answer.

```
insert Table_2 (Test) values( CONVERT(varbinary(30), N'this is a test') ) 
select * from Table_2
select CONVERT(nvarchar(30), test) from Table_2
```

So the C# code would look something like

```
    // Get from config
    string connectionString = "";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = "insert Table_2 (Test) values( CONVERT(varbinary(30), @nvarcharParam) )";
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            var param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nvarcharParam", "This is a test");
            param.DbType = DbType.String;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```